# Fatal error:Call to a member function result() on a non-object.(Codignighter)

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

Here is the code:

```
public function get_id_model($email){
    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    return $query->result();
}
```

This code works fine locally. But when I pushed the project to 000webhost it returned the null though my remote database contains data.

Database.php

```
$db['remote']['hostname'] = 'xxx.000webhost.com';
$db['remote']['username'] = 'xxx';
$db['remote']['password'] = 'xxx';
$db['remote']['database'] = 'xxx';
$db['remote']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['remote']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['remote']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['remote']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['remote']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['remote']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['remote']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['remote']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['remote']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['remote']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['remote']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

In Autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: You are using the old `mysql_` database API here `$db['remote']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';` If your hosting is using PHP7 it does not exist. Or maybe `000webhost` has turned the `mysql_` extension off?

Comment: I edited your question with what seemed to be actual login credentials. I highly suggest that you change them now, if those were actual credentials.

Comment: just change it to mysqli

Comment: @JamesLalor mysql to mysqli?

Comment: @IsmailRubad yes, CI will handle the rest.

Comment: so........... comment #2; nothing. Well hey... you've an answer below.

Answer (score -2):

Just change you database driver from mysql to mysqli. You do that in the database.php file in the config folder.

Comment: *"Just change you database driver from mysql to mysqli."* - That requires more detail. They can't just change their code from mysql to mysqli_, not without certain syntax to be adhered to.

Comment: @Fred-ii- actually this is perfectly acceptable answer, CI will handle the differences with it's own Database Driver Libraries. There actually does not need to be any more detail.